# Incorrect $query in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

This page is to predict the **City** that have maximum number of students and **Program** which is most popular for that particular city.

For an example, The most popular program in City A is Bachelor in IT because it has 100 students compare with other program in City A.

With the below query, I able to retrieve the city which have maximum number of students but not the popular program in that city.

```
$query = "SELECT student_city, count(*) AS count, student_prg 
          FROM marketing_data 
          GROUP BY student_city 
          ORDER by count desc 
          LIMIT 3;";
```

Can someone assist me to correct the $query according to my request? Thank you so much.

[image: Table Structure]

[image: Output]

**Sample Data**

```
mysql> select student_matric, student_prg, student_city from marketing_data;
        +----+---------------+------+----------+--------+
        | student_matric | student_prg| student_city
        +----+---------------+------+----------+--------+
        |  1             |   BIT      | Kuala Dungun 
        |  2             |   BSE      | Kuala Dungun
        |  3             |   BSE      | Kuala Dungun 
        |  4             |   BMI      | Kuala Dungun     
        |  5             |   BSC      | Jerantut
        |  6             |   BSC      | Jerantut 
        |  7             |   BMI      | Kuala Dungun
        |  8             |   BSE      | Bukit Beruntung
        |  9             |   DCS      | Bukit Beruntung
        |  10            |   DCS      | Bukit Beruntung
        |  11            |   BMI      | Gelugor
        |  12            |   BMI      | Gua Musung
        |  13            |   BMI      | Gua Musang
        |  14            |   BIT      | Kajang
        |  15            |   BMI      | Kampar
        |  16            |   BSE      | Nilai
        |  17            |   BMI      | Nusajaya
        +----+---------------+------+----------+--------+
```

**Expected output**

```
            +----+---------------+---------+
            | student_prg| student_city
            +----+---------------+---------+
            |   BSE      | Kuala Dungun 
            |   DCS      | Bukit Beruntung
```

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your question

Comment: You can only select column which are in the group by statement or aggregated values

Answer (score 0):

You need  also student_prg in group by

```
$query = "SELECT student_city, count(*) AS count, student_prg 
          FROM marketing_data 
          GROUP BY student_city, student_prg 
          ORDER by count desc,  student_city
          LIMIT 3;";
```

Comment: Hi @scaisEdge - The output is incorrect, the city with even 1 student is displaying...

Comment: You have also  Gua Musung and BMI  with 2  count  .. so you could obtain a different result 
 ( 4 city, prg with count 2 but limit to 3 )  ..   for others limit you must tell us which rule you want use  ..

Comment: Yes, u are right @scaisEdge... That's the second part I'm confused, but that's ok I will sort it out later. How about use limit 2 for the edited expected result as above?

Comment: you comment have not seems to  me  ..  if you want only two rows then use LIMIT 2  ...instead of LIMIT 3